# Can I cut the top off my Lace Aloe plant?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, plant-care, succulents, aloe

It is having trouble supporting its own weight, and I am hoping that cutting off the top (where it starts to droop) would let it grow more full, rather than just tall. Would that work? Does it work with all plants?? I have a few that seem to have this issue.

[image]

Comment: I dont think it is a aloe. The plant is a haworthia coarctata plant. It is its growth pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should most definitely remove the top! After you've done so, put your new little succulent in a shady spot for 3 days to allow it to callous over. After it has calloused, you can plant it in its own little pot. Wait at least 3-4 days before watering. In a few weeks you will notice pups growing from where you removed the top. You will be amazed with how many new plants you can end up with by propagating.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement, Andrea! I did this and now have 8 new healthy and growing aloe pups :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid cutting off the top from where it leans over will not solve the problem, because the problem is insufficient light - you will notice that the plant has the appearance of stretching and leaning over to get as close to daylight as possible.

You could try moving it to a brighter spot, directly in front of a window and as close as possible, with the leaning part turned in towards the room - hopefully, the plant's desire for light will mean it straightens up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But what if I were to cut the top off AND give it more light. Perhaps that will help it grow fuller?

Comment: It should grow fuller with increased light anyway - bear in mind that when you cut something back, it often produces two new stems where there was only one, so you might end up with two new shoots but  still no fuller at the base.

Answer (score 1):

I have only been able to get big XL aloe heads from the ground or outdoor planters which is the most beautiful.  I would cut the top off and replant both with the cutting deep to get its beauty back.  Move outside.  Water well.